# Redirect server to interpreter + get response

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, cgi, interpreter

**OK, let me explain what I need :**

- I have written an interpreter (for a language of my own design) and want to start trying it out as a server language
- I want to set it up so that all requests to files with a specific extension (e.g. `.xxx`), are redirected to my executable
- Whatever this executable outputs will be the server response.

I'm not a network/server guru, so I'd definitely need some help with that. (I imagine it might be something rather simple having to do with Apache configuration, but I still don't know...)

How would you go about it?

Comment: is your executable running on the same box with a different port ? If so, you could use mod_rewrite to forward the request to that port.

Comment: @Eric Well, I don't what you're talking about, regarding ports. It's a plain executable, which takes a filename as a parameter and executes it. And yes, it's running on the same server (Debian Wheezy + Apache, if that matters at all)

Comment: What I mean is that the easy way to achieve this is to have your executable running as a service and listening on a port. Instead of trying to call the executable, forward to request to the port your executable listens to and has it handle the request.

Comment: @Eric Hmmm, interesting idea; though (being almost network-illiterate lol) I'll have to read up a bit on the subject. Thanks a lot, anyway! :-)

Comment: Np, this isn't that hard, if you can program a socket, you can achieve this